# How can I connect to a kitchen printer (or any receipt printer) and make it print custom online orders?

Tags: design, api-design

If I were building an online food ordering app but I wanted to print a receipt to the kitchen, how would I do that?

There are many SaaS solutions available like Uber Eats and other apps that allow the customers to order food online but all the orders just show up on the tablet they give. What if the kitchen was huge or the receipt was massive, how would the person at the front tell the kitchen exactly what they need? Would they have to re-write it on a paper or something?

Regardless, the tablet solution is easy to implement. Is it possible to connect to a small recipt/kitchen printer through the internet and send it a request to print an order with X items? I've been searching around but I can't seem to find a solution to this. Most printers have bluetooth (which I don't think can help me in this case) and some say they connect using an ethernet cable, but I haven't found any info on if/how I can connect to the printer and make it print orders.

I've searched around and I've found some other software that say they can send online orders to the kitchen printer. How do they do this?

Alternatively, if you have any suggestions as to how I should handle online orders I'm all ears! Thanks

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: Well in that comment it says "Assume that the answer is 'yes' and start designing the software. When you have a problem, then ask about that problem." So I started designing and as I mentioned I found out that all of them seem to have Bluetooth and Ethernet but I found no information on getting it to do custom prints over the internet which is the problem I'm at now. So I'm not sure where to go from there... I just thought to maybe ask people who'd know more so they can point me in the right direction because so far it seems it's not possible.

Comment: This keeps getting down voted so I assume I did something wrong, but I'm not entirely sure what I did wrong. I did my research, got stuck, and came for help. If someone could let me know why this is a bad question or how I could improve it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: There are just so many questions here that's it's difficult how to even start answering it.  It's at the point where you are asking us how to design a whole solution for you (without seeing all the requirements), rather than answering some specific software design question.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage of your design, a kitchen receipt printer is not really all that different from a regular office printer (sure, it only has a single color and takes narrower paper from a roll rather than sheets, but do you really really care about that while you are still figuring out how to print anything at all?). So, don't worry too much about what makes kitchen receipt printers special.

Printers are invariably designed around a push principle: "I am sitting here waiting for you to tell me to do something." Cloud solutions on the other hand are designed around a pull principle: The client software decides what it needs and retrieves that. If you try to hook a push-based client to a pull-based (cloud) server, nothing is going to happen as they both will be waiting on each other.

The solution to connect the printer to the SaaS solution is to implement the printing functionality in the client software of the SaaS solution. The client software can then retrieve the relevant orders from the cloud and (directly or after interaction with the user) send the orders on to a connected printer.